# Can anyone assist in converting an element of code in order that it will run?

Tags: r, idl, satellite

I am 'translating' some code provided in IDL into R.

There are a number of elements, one of which I am currently struggling with.

The below code is broadly intended to compute that;

where RelAA is greater than 180, the value should be converted to 360 - [said value] and where RelAA is less than 180, the value should be converted to 180 - [said value].

In IDL it is as follows;

```
calculate relative azimuth angle (RelAzm)
RelAA = ABS((sazm) - (vazm))
index_gt180 = where(RelAA gt 180.d)
index_lt180 = where(RelAA lt 180.d)
RelAA[index_gt180] = 360.- RelAA[index_gt180]
RelAA[index_lt180] = 180.- RelAA[index_lt180]
```

I've tried to use an ifelse function in R, which would not work.

I also tried to use the below, but it appears not to have worked.

```
relaa[relaa > 180] = 360 - relaa[relaa > 180]
relaa[relaa < 180] = 180 - relaa[relaa < 180]
```

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

```
relaa[relaa > 180] = 360 - relaa[relaa > 180]
relaa[relaa < 180] = 180 - relaa[relaa < 180]

calculate relative azimuth angle (RelAzm)
RelAA = ABS((sazm) - (vazm))
index_gt180 = where(RelAA gt 180.d)
index_lt180 = where(RelAA lt 180.d)
RelAA[index_gt180] = 360.- RelAA[index_gt180]
RelAA[index_lt180] = 180.- RelAA[index_lt180]
```

The expected outcome would be a list of corrected values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question, but if I understand correctly, you were on the right track with the `ifelse` command.

Two example values:

```
relaa <- c(181,179)
```

Now applying the `ifelse` command, you specify what condition needs to be fulfilled (`relaa > 180`), what happens if the condition is fulfilled (`360 - relaa`), and what happens if the condition is not fulfilled (`180 - relaa`):

```
relaa2 <- ifelse(relaa > 180, 360 - relaa, 180 - relaa)
```

This yields:

```
> relaa2
[1] 179   1
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I've got an outcome using the below:

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer using the below code;

```
relaa = ifelse(relaa[] > 180, 360 - relaa[], ifelse(relaa[] < 180, 180 - relaa[],
relaa[]))
```

However, I now have the issue that the outcome has become numeric. I need to retain the original 'raster' format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(raster)
relaa <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
relaa <- init(relaa, "x") + 180
```

Solution 1

```
m <- relaa > 180
mT <- mask(relaa, m, maskvalue=TRUE)
mT <- 180 - mT
x <- cover(mT, 360-relaa)
```

Solution 2

```
y <- calc(relaa, function(x) ifelse(x >= 180, 360-x, 180-x))
```

Solution 3 (using a non-exported, and not much tested, function)

```
z <- raster:::.ifel(relaa >= 180, 360 - relaa, 180 - relaa)
```

Solution 4 (not recommended; as it may lead to memory problems). You were close, but you had the order wrong to avoid that some cell values got changed twice.

```
relaa[relaa < 180] = 180 - relaa[relaa < 180]
relaa[relaa > 180] = 360 - relaa[relaa > 180]
```